# Jquery preloader animation works but is it a gimmick or is it actually calculating site load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

I am using [this] pre-loader for my personal portfolio.

```
var h = window.innerHeight;
            $('.page-overlay').css('height',h);
            var al = 0;
            function progressSim(){
              document.querySelector('.page-overlay>.text>p').innerHTML = 
al+'%';
              if(al>=100){
                  clearTimeout(sim);
                }
                al++;
              }
              var sim = setInterval(progressSim,50);
              $('.body, .navbar').hide();

              setTimeout(function(){
                $('.page-overlay').hide();
                $('.body,.navbar').show();
              },5500);
```

HTML is like this:

```
<body>
        <div class="page-overlay">
                <div class="text"><p></p></div>
                  <div class="paper-progress-bar"></div>
              </div>
<! header, followed by container divs and loads of paragraphs>
</body>
```

Also, the script is before the closing tag of the body. The animation works fine, it goes from zero to hundred on the page overlay then it shows the body beneath it. But there are two problems here:

1. I am not sure if this script is actually waiting for the body to load. Note that I am right now coding on local and I don't know if there is any other way to test this. When the website goes live, will this script actually show the percentage of page load? or is it just a simulation or wait time?
2. I've added the ('.body, .navbar').hide(); but it doesn't work. To add to the gimmick I've set the page-overlay to fixed position with z-index set to high. But the scroll bar is active and the body behind also active while the page is loading. If I am setting the body class display to none it's hiding everything including the page-overlay.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. This is my first question on stackoverflow and first time building a website so apologies for any mistakes in question.

p.p.s. I'm using this as preloader https://codepen.io/sanjay8bisht/pen/wKPqVd

Answer (score 0):

I'll start from the second question. The body and navbar hide doesn't work, because you added a "." before the body string.

**And the first question:**

If we explore the script:

get the window's height.

```
var h = window.innerHeight;
```

set the overlay over the page with the height of the page height

```
$('.page-overlay').css('height',h);
```

create a variable for keeping the 0 to 100 counter:

```
var al = 0;
```

create a function which simulates the page load, later we'll use it

```
function progressSim(){
```

show the load counter in a paragraph element on the overlay

```
    document.querySelector('.page-overlay>.text>p').innerHTML = al+'%';
```

if the value reaches 100 or overrides 100:

```
    if(al>=100){
```

stop the loop function.

```
       clearTimeout(sim);

    }
```

increase the page load counter.

```
    al++;
```

finish the function.

```
}
```

---

Now the real part:

repeat the above function with 50 milliseconds interval, so counting from 0 to 100 would take: 50 * 100 : 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds).

```
var sim = setInterval(progressSim,50);
```

at the same time, hide the body and the navbar:

```
$('.body, .navbar').hide();
```

then after 5500ms (5.5secs) elapses, hide the overlay, and show the body and navbar again.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('.page-overlay').hide();
   $('.body,.navbar').show();
},5500);
```

What do you think? It's just an animation. Not a real loader.

You may look at this one: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/ for something more reliable.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation and help but I am finding pace.js complicated to implement. Can you recommend something simpler?